# Store generated id in variable to be used in following insert statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql script which I want to execute via `\i` using `psql` or `pgcli`. In this script I want to do something like:

```
insert into parent_table ... returning id;

insert into child_table ... values (id_from_above, ...);
insert into child_table ... values (id_from_above, ...);
insert into child_table ... values (id_from_above, ...);
```

Is it somehow possible to store the generated id and use it in multiple future insert statements?

Comment: Use a single query, a CTE and do everything at once. That also makes it a single transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [declare a variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) and execute the whole code using [DO statement](https://docs.postgresql.fr/current/sql-do.html).

For exemple:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
my_id integer ;

BEGIN

insert into parent_table ... returning id into my_id;

insert into child_table ... values (my_id, ...);
insert into child_table ... values (my_id, ...);
insert into child_table ... values (my_id, ...);

END $$;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Can you tell me where I could have found the DO-syntax in the docs?

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.postgresql.fr/current/sql-do.html